# Python adding "\u" to string

Tags: python, unicode

I have a string "E001" 
I would like to add "\u" to the beginning of that string
So the code would look something like this:

```
output = add_u("E001")
print(output)
--------------------------
OUTPUT: \uE001
```

There are difficulties with this I keep getting a Unicode error

Comment: Ok, and what happened when you tried the approaches from your research?

Comment: What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: It's a simple string concatenation; the only tricky part is that you need to escape the backslash.

Comment: The things that kept happening in my research where: it kept adding more then one \ or gave a Unicode error

Comment: My ultimate goal is that there is a json file that remaps unicode characters to images so it would be like {"char":"\uE001","file":"path/to/image"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def add_u(s):
    return r'\u' + s

print(add_u('E001'))
```

Outputs:

```
\uE001
```

Comment: This worked! What exactly does the r in front of the string mean? I have come across when I tried to solve this on my own but I find the meaning unclear.

Comment: The r means raw string literal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals

Comment: So when I add this string to a list it adds a second "\",
a_list = ["\uE001"] becomes ["\\uE001"] is there any way to prevent this? I have the string in a variable if you do this literally nothing will happen but if you return a variable from a function and put that in a list then this happens

Comment: You're looking at the representation of the string, not at the string content. If you have `x = '\\` in your code then `x` will be a string with one character, the backslash. See the difference with `print(x, repr(x))`.

Answer (score 2):

How about just:

```
output = "\\u" + "E001"
print(output)
```

Or as a function:

```
def add_u(string):
    return "\\u" + string

output = add_u("E001")
print(output)
```

Handles backslash escaping.